# Application fails due to unexpected outOfmemory error.

Tags: java, memory, jvm, glassfish-3

I have a java application which is running in glassfish 3.1.1

Once the ps old generation reach max (-Xmx is 512m), it drops, but my whole application hangs and dies, it throws `outOfmemory:java heap space`.

I do not understand why since the ps old generation already dropped
 The only fix is a server restart.

I need application to continue ps old generation drops.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor your server and restart the server with a srcipt if necessary.

Comment: what i want is to release ps old generation once it hit like 98% before it reach max, since it dies.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the memory usage come down due to shutdown process. The outOfmemory exception clearly indicates that it is dying because of insufficient memory.

There are options to finetune the size of old generation for instance. But you should take a heap snapshot and examine if all the data that is getting stored is necessary. There may be some memory leak or it may be necessary to increase the available memory of the application.

Comment: thank you for your reply. 1. you mentioned "a heap snapshot and examine if all the data that is getting stored is necessary", all i am doing is to get the data from database and store in request. are you recommand to get less information from database ?  2. i increased -Xms, but once application runs longer, i ran into the same problem

Comment: Are you storing it in the request.getSession() object? How much data from the database are you storing in your request?

Comment: sorry, i was not storing in request. but on each page i was displaying about 50 images from database and each image is less than 200k, then i use outputstream to write byte[] to my web app

Comment: You take heap dump either when application goes out of memory or you can explicitly invoke it using tools like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_local.html It is possible that the images you are loading remain in memory somehow dues to some lingering references. You can be sure about the cause only after you analyze whats taking up memory.

Comment: i just got more details: after outOfMemory issues happens, i tried to open a web page, it fails, but when i look at the log files, the app send out http request all the way to the back end, until it hits preparestetment.executQuery(), "outOfMemorry: java heap space" exception is thrown. it application dies, then nothing should happen, right? then why app still send out http request to back end

Comment: i was using a static connection object for all the user connection, once more users use this connection the ps old generation build up. solutions:  1. i use one connection per call, which is not a good idea, since too expensive. 2. have a try / catch, if outOfMemorry exception is thrown, catch it and get new connection object, and re-execute the method.